# Microsoft access Query design

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT 
    Item.Itemno 
    , SUM(Delivered_item.qtyordered) AS SumOfqtyordered 
    , SUM(Item_issued.qtyissued) AS SumOfqtyissued
FROM  
    Item  
    INNER JOIN Delivered_item ON Item.Itemno = Delivered_item.itemno 
    INNER JOIN Item_issued ON Item.Itemno = Item_issued.Itemno
GROUP BY  
    Item.Itemno;
```

This is my sql view. In my database, `delivered_item` has 7 records whilst `item_issued` only has 2 records. When I perform `SUM`, the total for the `qtyissued` gets wrong, with 1 record(`qtyissued`) multiply by 3 and another record multiply by 4, due to the `delivered_item` having 7 records(with 2 same `itemno`)...how can solve this...

Comment: Can you show us your sample data and your expected result?

Comment: This query will not run in an Access SQL environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use sub-queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM item i
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT itemno,
          Sum(qtyordered)
   FROM delivereditem
   GROUP BY itemno) d ON d.itemno = i.itemno
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT itemno,
          Sum(qtyissued)
   FROM itemissued
   GROUP BY itemno) iss ON iss.itemno = i.itemno
```

If you think you might have to do this a lot, turn each of the subqueries into a view and use that instead (saves on typing)

EDIT: Added the group by's in the subqueries. Sorry about that!

Comment: Can you guide me more on that?Im a beginner and not sure what is subquery. Thanks

Comment: There are two subqueries in  the answer, the two selects enclosed in (). In general, where-ever you can have a table name, you can substitute a select statement. These are called subqueries. Did the statement above work?

Comment: select *
from Item i
inner join
(select itemno, sum(qtyOrdered) from delivered_Item
) delivered_item on delivered_item.itemNo = item.itemNo
inner join
(
   select itemno, sum(qtyIssued) from itemIssued
) item_issued on item_issued.itemNo = item.itemNo

Comment: so i just drag the related tables for the query and then try ur code in sql view right

Comment: delivered_item on delivered_item.itemNo = item.itemNo
inner join
(select itemno, sum(qtyIssued) from item_Issued group by itemno) item_issued on item_issued.itemNo = item.itemNo

Comment: Just noticed I got the table names wrong. Did you correct that? deliveredIien and issuedItem instead of delivered_item and issued_item?

Comment: i have added my sql code at above, is there anything wrong?

Comment: simon, nvm, i now created 2queries(delivered and issued), in each query, i include itemno from item table and qtydelivered or qtyissued.What should i do next to combine and calculate balance?

Comment: This getting a bit long now. Can you open another question showing where you are and what you want get to?